# Export DataFrame timedelta column to timestamp Excel column

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, xlsxwriter

I have a DataFrame that contains a `datetime64` and a `timedelta64`. Unfortunately, I can't export the latter to a properly formatted `hh:mm:ss` column in an Excel file:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "date": [
        "2023-02-05",
        "2023-02-05",
        "2022-12-02",
        "2022-11-29",
        "2022-11-18",
    ],
    "duration": [
        "01:07:48",
        "05:23:06",
        "02:41:58",
        "00:35:11",
        "02:00:20",
    ],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df['duration'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['duration'])

with pd.ExcelWriter(
    "df.xlsx",
    datetime_format="YYYY-MM-DD",
    engine="xlsxwriter",
) as writer:
    workbook = writer.book
    time_format = workbook.add_format({"num_format": "HH:MM:SS"})
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="sheet", index=False)
    worksheet = writer.sheets["sheet"]
    worksheet.set_column("A:A", 20)
    worksheet.set_column("B:B", 50, cell_format=time_format)
```

The resulting Excel file will display like this:

[image: Excel file]

So, the `date_time` format in the `ExcelWriter` object is applied correctly for column A, as well as the width setting for column B, but the number formatting isn't working.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that the column format isn't being applied is that Pandas is applying a cell [number format of "0"](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/io/excel/_base.py#L1302) to the timedelta values. The cell format overrides the column format so that isn't applied. You can verify this by adding the following at the end of the `with` statement and you will see that it is formatted as expected:

```py
    worksheet.write(7, 1, .5)
```

I'm not sure what is the best way to work around but you could iterate over the timedelta values and rewrite them out to override the pandas formatted values. Something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "date": [
        "2023-02-05",
        "2023-02-05",
        "2022-12-02",
        "2022-11-29",
        "2022-11-18",
    ],
    "duration": [
        "01:07:48",
        "05:23:06",
        "02:41:58",
        "00:35:11",
        "02:00:20",
    ],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df['duration'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['duration'])

with pd.ExcelWriter(
    "df.xlsx",
    datetime_format="YYYY-MM-DD",
    engine="xlsxwriter",
) as writer:
    workbook = writer.book
    time_format = workbook.add_format({"num_format": "HH:MM:SS"})
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="sheet", index=False)
    worksheet = writer.sheets["sheet"]
    worksheet.set_column("A:A", 20)
    worksheet.set_column("B:B", 50, cell_format=time_format)

    col = df.columns.get_loc('duration')
    for row, timedelta in enumerate(df['duration'], 1):
        worksheet.write(row, col, timedelta)
```

**Output:**

[image]

You could also covert the timedelta back to a number (like Pandas does) since dates or times in Excel are just numbers anyway with a format.

Something like this, which will give the same result as above:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df['duration'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['duration']).dt.total_seconds() / 86400

with pd.ExcelWriter(
    "df.xlsx",
    datetime_format="YYYY-MM-DD",
    engine="xlsxwriter",
) as writer:
    workbook = writer.book
    time_format = workbook.add_format({"num_format": "HH:MM:SS"})
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="sheet", index=False)
    worksheet = writer.sheets["sheet"]
    worksheet.set_column("A:A", 20)
    worksheet.set_column("B:B", 50, cell_format=time_format)
```

Comment: Thanks! The second way looks like the best to me. I find it very odd that the formatting *in Excel* is different depending on whether the values are stored as timedelta or float.

Comment: Strictly speaking the format is different in Excel because Pandas is applying a different format for timedelta and ordinary floats. In Excel they are both just floats.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Excel is measuring your time in day units. For example, for your first value, (1:07:48 = 4068s) you are getting a duration of (4048/(24*3600)) days.

You have the posible solutions here:
[formatting timedelta64 when using pandas.to_excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46523178/formatting-timedelta64-when-using-pandas-to-excel)

Comment: Thanks, but the solutions provided in that post don't appear to work with the case described above.